# How to Optimize this Neo4j Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this cypher query that I had written:

```
MATCH (SubjectUserNode:User:Transaction {NodeID: "2547:12109:000:381864"})-[dimensionRelation:LegalEntity
    WHERE dimensionRelation.Status = "1"
]->(dimension:LegalEntity:Transaction)<-[udimensionRelation:LegalEntity
    WHERE udimensionRelation.Status = "1"
]-(User:User:Transaction)-[RoleRelationship:Role
    WHERE RoleRelationship.Status = "1"
]->(Role:Role:Transaction {NodeID: "2547:12122:000:70163"})
RETURN User.TransactionID as UserID
```

In this query, I'm trying to get all those User nodes that are related to a given Role node(NodeID given) and are also related to the LegalEntity node which has a relation to the given User node(NodeID given).

Example:

[image: Node image]

The query profile is:

[image: Query Profile]

The query is taking between 4-5 seconds to return the data and the number of nodes being returned is about 150.

Is there anyway to improve this query like by using any apoc procedure? I can't think of any other way as according to me this is a simple query in itself. Also, indices are already created on the nodeID of each node type.

Comment: How many dimensionRelation.Status values are there? You can create an index in this relationship OR create another relatiinship specific to dimensionRelation.Status=1.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your visualization seems to indicate you have 2 `User` nodes with the same `NodeID` (12109). Is that unintended?

Comment: @cybersam `12109` is not a `NodeID` it's just a property value which indicates that it's a `User` node. The `NodeID` is like: `2547:12109:000:381864` which is unique for every node. The visualizer is just picking up this `12109` property value to show on the node.

Comment: @jose_bacoy there are 4 possible values for the `dimensionRelation.Status` property. I don't think it would be possible to create a separate relationship just for a single Status value.

Comment: @Garv; let's have a chat room or zoom meeting to discuss this. I see that LegalEntity is both a node and relationship type, so there are so much things to discuss. thanks.

Comment: @cybersam; do you notice the incorrect number format on the profiling?  It reads 30,92,064db hits instead of 3,092,064db hits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be spending most of its time scanning through all the possible `SubjectUserNode` candidates.

So, try adding an index on `User.NodeID`. The execution planner should be able to use that index to reduce the execution time.

##### Addendum

Also, unless logically required, you should simplify your query to remove unnecessary filtering, which wastes time. For example, if all `User` nodes are also `Transaction` nodes, use `(SubjectUserNode:User ...)` instead of `(SubjectUserNode:User:Transaction ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As per meeting with Garv (and also from @cybersam previous answer), removing :Transaction label on the query fixed the slow performance. The query is doing a table scan because all data in the database is labeled as Transaction.  After the fix, the run time is now 6ms vs 3.4s before.

```
MATCH (subjectUserNode:User{NodeID: "2547:12109:000:381864"})-[dimensionRelation:LegalEntity
    WHERE dimensionRelation.Status = "1"
]->(dimension:LegalEntity)<-[udimensionRelation:LegalEntity
    WHERE udimensionRelation.Status = "1"
]-(user:User)-[roleRelationship:Role
    WHERE roleRelationship.Status = "1"
]->(role:Role{NodeID: "2547:12122:000:70163"})
RETURN user.TransactionID as UserID
```